# Peierls's argument for the Ising model

Tags: thermodynamics, ising-model, ferromagnetism

I was reading about [Peierls's argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Basic_properties_and_history) for the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) at this [link](https://renormalwords.wordpress.com/2017/04/20/the-peierls-argument/) and got a question.

The Hamiltonian is $$ H = -J \sum_{(i,j)} \sigma_i \sigma_j - \sum_i h_i \sigma_i $$ with the first summation extending over nearest neighbours, $J > 0$.

They talk about both $1$ and $2$D and I have the same question for both cases, although for the one-dimensional case it does not affect the final conclusion.

The competition between energy $U$ and entropy $S$ in the free energy $F = U - TS $ is considered.
For the $2$D case it is said that the energy difference between a completely ordered lattice with spins pointing up and a configuration with an island of spins pointing downwards, of perimeter $L$ equals

$$\Delta U = 2JL$$

To estimate the entropy contribution it is therein said " the number of ways to build an island **which includes a fixed spin X** " (bold mine) is roughly $$\mu^L$$, where $\mu$ is a number less than $3$.

The change in free energy is hence
$$ \Delta F = 2JL -kT L \log \mu$$ and contrary to the $1$D case both terms scale with $L$ and they can effectively compete to the point that a magnetisation different from $0$ appears at a sufficiently low temperature.

I do not understand why entropy is estimated with the condition of imposing the "flipped island" has to contain a fixed spin $X$.

The change in energy is independent of the location of the island. Wherever the flipped island appears, the energy change is the same. But the flipped island can appear anywhere on the lattice, why is this not accounted for in the entropy estimate?

Should not entropy be computed, including all the islands, with fixed perimeter $L$?

It seems at first sight entropy is severely underestimated if this fixed spin constraint is exerted.

Comment: Should this be tagged with [ferromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/ferromagnetism/info) (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: Good point, will do

Comment: "The change in free entropy is hence ... ". You mean free energy.

Comment: @Andrea Alciato, you of course correct, I edited thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peierls argument is to show that it is favorable to create a domain *here* (wherever the experimenter defines as "here"). In the thermodynamic limit, if it's favorable to create a domain "here", then it's favorable to create a domain anywhere else, and the whole system becomes disordered (i.e. the ordered state is not stable).

It's not enough to argue that it's favorable to create a domain wall *anywhere*. In the thermodynamic limit, it's always favorable, since as you pointed out, that entropic contribution scales with the system size. But that doesn't tell you anything about the phase: just because there's a domain *somewhere*, doesn't mean the system has become disordered. You need to show that the domain can be created "here" (and by symmetry, that means it's favorable to create domains everywhere, and put the system in disorder).

EDIT: more details to follow.

I believe your qualm is with the style of the argument, which I agree is a little unintuitive. Here's how I understand it.

Imagine we flip a single island of size $L$, some very large distance away. Compute the magnetization now. It's still 1 (or -1) because in the thermodynamic limit, the contribution of a single island is negligible. So, this (by itself) doesn't tell us anything about the emergence of the disordered phase.

Ok, but of course we are interested in the case where islands can spontaneously pop up anywhere and everywhere, thus truly changing the magnetization even in the thermodynamic limit. As you pointed out in the original question, the "perfect" calculation will involve computing the energy and entropy changes of any number of islands of any size. These calculations (which directly account for fluctuations) are extremely hard to do.

As a proxy for the "perfect" calculation, we use Peierls argument: compute the $\Delta F$ of a single island, and then extrapolate it to the multiple-island case. But in order for this extrapolation to make sense, we have to only consider local fluctuations (i.e. islands that appear at a particular place). The reason is because being able to flip one island at an arbitrary location doesn't imply that it's favorable to flip islands everywhere; as you add more islands, the premise of the original calculation breaks down. On the other hand, if a *local* fluctuation is favorable, then it *does* follow that fluctuations everywhere are favorable.

Comment: thanks for this but I struggle to follow. You say "s not enough to argue that it's favorable to create a domain wall anywhere. In the thermodynamic limit, it's always favorable", ok then, but this alone should prove that a domain will appear anyhow. In other words, the system will get disordered. I also do not fully understand the statement, "just because there's a domain somewhere, doesn't mean the system has become disordered"...Would you please consider adding some details?

Comment: @Smerdjakov I've updated with more details, let me know if this helps

Comment: thanks makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to take a look  at this paper: [NEW PROOFS OF LONG RANGE ORDER](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-08853-9_5.pdf) written by E. Lieb.

In this paper, Lieb reviews how the original, exact form of Peierls argument was derived. In paticular, the Peierls' result bounds the probablity of two distant spins being opposite, say $p_{+-}$, to be

$$p_{+-} \leq \sum_{L=4}^\infty \exp\left[ -(2\beta J - \ln 3) L \right]$$

this proves, mathematically, that the long range order exists for 2D Ising model at sufficiently low temperature.

There are rigorous physical arguments that can easily relates the $2J L$ to be the $\Delta U$, while the $L \ln 3$ to be the configurational entropy $\Delta S$ of a boundary with length $L$. I am conjecturing that during the 90 years history of Peierls' result, this rigorous proof gradullay evolves into a somewhat inaccurate *argument*, as the one which is currently confusing you.